# Reading reserved keyword column name of MSACCESS using c# code

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am creating a application which is having database as MSACCESS.
one of the column name in the database is "Date", when i try to read the column using C# CODE its says "No value given for one or more required parameter"

```
    SELECT [DATE] FROM TABLE1
```

Is there any way we read the **reserved keyword** columns in c# coding.

please help

Comment: 1. Does TABLE1 really have field named DATE. 2. Try full name: SELECT TABLE1.[DATE] FROM TABLE1   3. use alias SELECT TABLE1.[DATE] as [BadlyNamedColumn] FROM TABLE1 4. May be error in your C# code?

Comment: Yes the Date column exist in Table1

Comment: `SELECT [DATE] FROM TABLE1` is a valid query. If you want us to help you then you'll need to edit your question and tell us what you are *actually* doing.

Answer (score 2):

> "No value given for one or more required parameter"

This is generated because you are not passing parameters properly to query.

For example

```
"select name from table where name="+abc+";
```

this kind of thing generate this problem as `' '` are missing.

Or you are providing less parameters in query for prepared statement.
*(there may be some other reasons)*

Please check.

Because I don't find anything wrong with this

```
SELECT [Date] FROM TABLE1
```